# GM_xmlhttpRequest through proxy server

Tags: javascript, post, proxy, get, greasemonkey

I don't have a specific problem regarding this yet, it's more that I can't start working until I know this and can't dig up an answer, so I'll use some random snippets I have lying around to demonstrate.

Say I have the script:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
method: "GET",
url: server + "SyncWatcher/get.php?ckey=" + privatekey,
onload: function(response) {
document.getElementById("cfinder").innerHTML+="<span id='kswlst' style='display:none;'>" + response.responseText + "</span>";}});
```

And a random proxy server, lets say 188.2.38.197:8080

How do I go about making the request through the proxy?

---

Okay, an edit to make it a specific question:

I have a php page containing

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "<br>" . $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

And am loading it into a div on a test page using:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
method: "GET",
url: "the get page",
proxy: "188.2.38.197",
port: "8080",
onload: function(response) {
document.getElementById("targin").innerHTML=response.responseText;
}
});
```

However, the IPs it loads are still my own address, so it isn't using the proxy.
How do I make it use the supplied proxy server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is no `proxy` property for `GM_xmlhttpRequest()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest).  (Nor is there one for [plain `XMLHttpRequest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).)

Normally for an ISP or company proxy, you [set Firefox to use that proxy](http://www.wikihow.com/Enter-Proxy-Settings-in-Firefox) per your provider's instructions.  `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` will then automatically use that proxy, as long as the target site is not in Firefox's "No Proxy" list.

Your code would just be:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method: "GET",
    url:    "AN ORDINARY URL THAT IS *NOT* IN THE 'NO PROXY' LIST",
    onload: function (response) {
        document.getElementById ("targin").innerHTML=response.responseText;
    }
} );
```

---

For one-off, or selective-use proxies, they typically get the target URL via a URL parameter or a form post.  You need to determine the details for the proxy you are using.

In that case, you would point to the ***proxy*** URL, and give the appropriate data.
For example, suppose your proxy accepted `GET` requests and was configured like so:

```
Proxy IP:   188.2.38.197
Port:       8080
Path:       GimmeGimme
Parameter:  thisUrl
```

Then you would fetch your page like so:

```
var targetURL   = "http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/";
var ajaxURL     = 'http://188.2.38.197:8080/GimmeGimme?thisUrl='
                + encodeURIComponent (targetURL)
                ;
GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method: "GET",
    url:    ajaxURL,
    onload: function (response) {
        document.getElementById ("targin").innerHTML=response.responseText;
    }
} );
```

Comment: Soory it took me so long to see this, it is exactly what i needed though, thanks :)